# Need help to understand how blade and controllers/routes interact

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-blade

i've been learning Laravel for a few months and im still really lost. I've been doing okay with the basics but now I need to use blade components to trigger some events and i have no idea how to do it.

I would like to display 2 checkbox in a view (Like "Create new 'entity'" and "Use existing 'entity'"). If I click on the first checkbox, I would like to make visible some text forms (making them invisible by default), and if I click on the second I would like to make visible a combobox with my 'entitys' loaded. When I select an 'entity', I would like to make some visible text forms displaying all the selected 'entity' info with an sqlquery.

The problem I see is that I don't really understand how blade interact with the controllers and routes. I've been trying to look for some tutorials but I can't find exactly what I need, maybe i'm not using the right words. Also it's getting harder to me cause English speaker and also I don't know the right way to name things in laravel yet, I hope you guys understand me.

If someone can link me some related tutorials to this or explain me how do blade interact with other stuff it would be awesome.

Thanks to everyone!

Comment: Blade is Laravel's templating engine and is used to build views in Laravel. Views are the part of the application that the user sees and interacts with. In Laravel, the views are usually created using Blade templates.

When you create a new blade component, you can add it to your view by calling the component's tag. The component's logic is contained within the component file, and can be passed variables from the view.

Comment: Give this a try: [Laravel Bootcamp](https://bootcamp.laravel.com/)

Comment: Thank you all for the answers, I will check the links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller functions are only accessible from the routes. From the blade you have to send a request to a specific route if you want to access for a controller function. (Send request from a form etc...)

In your case I highly recomend for you the Livewire framework, it allows an easy to understand communication between blade and component.

https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/quickstart

But if you don`t want to use Livewire for some reason, you should use AJAX to communicate with controller.

https://www.positronx.io/laravel-ajax-example-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks, this looks good, I will check this Livewire thing.